# Matriz intercalada

Tags: java, matriz

Olá, estou fazendo este exercício, mas estou tendo uma dificuldade. Segue o enunciado:

> 22) Escreva um programa para gerar uma matriz (N x M) (<=20) e outra (N x
>   P) (<=20). Gerar uma terceira matriz (N x (M+P)) (<=20 x <=40), sendo que
>   para cada linha intercalar suas respectivas colunas e apresentar as três matrizes.

Eis o código que já tenho:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex22 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n, a = 0, b = 0;

        do {
            System.out.printf("Entre com o tamanho da matriz: ");
            n = leia.nextInt();
        } while (n > 20);

        int [][] m = new int [n][n];

        System.out.printf("\nMatriz M:\n");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                m[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9+1);
                System.out.printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

        do {
            System.out.printf("\nEntre com o tamanho da matriz: ");
            n = leia.nextInt();
        } while (n > 20);

        int [][] p = new int [n][n];

        System.out.printf("\nMatriz P:\n");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                p[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 9+1);
                System.out.printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

        int [][] q = new int [n][n+n];

        System.out.printf("\nMatriz Q:\n");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<(n+n); ){
                q[i][j] = m[i][a];
                a++;
                j++;

                q[i][j] = p[i][b];
                b++;
                j++;                
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<(n+n); j++){
                System.out.printf("%d ", q[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Alguém sabe porque está dando estouro?

Comment: Alguém sabe porque está dando estouro?
Esse é o erro que retorna:

 Matriz Q:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Ex22.main(Ex22.java:53)

Mas em C ele compila sem erros.

Comment: Você não reinicia `a` e `b` no for da matriz q, não analisei o resto do código, mas você tá considerando que n = m = p e não é isso que a questão pede também...

Comment: Michael Martins, compilar ele compila normalmente, mas entre compilar e executar há uma diferença enorme.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você está lendo `n` duas vezes, mas você deveria ler `n`, `m` e `p` de forma independente.

Depois o trecho mais problemático é este:

```java
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<(n+n); ){
            q[i][j] = m[i][a];
            a++;
            j++;

            q[i][j] = p[i][b];
            b++;
            j++;                
        }
    }
```

Observe o `a++;` e o `b++;`, vão fazer cada um ir de `0` até `2n²` e não acho que é isso que você quer, uma vez que ao acessar `m[i][a]` ou `p[i][b]` você terá um indíce de coluna fora do intervalo válido, e portanto a exceção:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at Ex22.main(Ex22.java:46)
```

Provavelmente está faltando um `a = 0;` e um `b = 0;` em algum lugar.

Comment: Exatamante. a=b=0

Obrigado a todos ^^